# Python console game

Tags: python, python-3.x

I develop a game using python for fun.
In here I generate gems inside a room and users can collect those gems.
Up to now gems are generated inside the rooms but they are not randomly generated. Also, after the user picks up the gem from the room it it is visible when coming back to the room again.

I cannot find a way to implement randomly generate gems inside the rooms and when to pick up gems user level have to upgrade and after coming back to same room gem must be changed.

Thank you

```
import random

# Rooms have items, players can carry items
class Item:
    def __init__(self, name, level):
        self.name = name
        self.level = level

# Create Gems
White_Gem = Item("White Gem","1")            
Yellow_Gem = Item("Yellow Gem","2")            
Green_Gem = Item("Green Gem","3")            
Red_Gem = Item("Red Gem","4")            
Blue_Gem = Item("Blue Gem","5")            

def make_gem():
    gem_in = random.randrange(2)
    if gem_in == (0 or 1):
        return 0
    gem = random.randrange(5)
    if gem == 0:
        gem = White_Gem
    elif gem == 1:
        gem = Yellow_Gem
    elif gem == 2:
        gem = Green_Gem
    elif gem == 3:
        gem = Red_Gem
    elif gem == 4:
        gem = Blue_Gem
    return gem
     
# Room class
class Room(object):
    """ Room """
    def __init__(self,name,description,gem_y_n):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.gem_y_n = gem_y_n
        if self.gem_y_n == "y":
            gem = make_gem()
            self.gem = gem

# Rooms
# last input is coordinates (n,e,s,w)
#
# ++++ Room Map +++++
#
# ===================
# |                 |
# |                 |
# |        1        |
# |                 |
# |     3  2        |
# |     4  5        |
# |     6           |
# |     7  8  9     |
# |           10    |
# |       12  11    |
# ===================
#
# Template:
# room# = Room(name,description,gem in it? (y/n))
# Then add the coordinates below the room creators

room1 = Room("Bedroom","You are you in your own bedroom.\nTo the south, there is a garden past the back door.", "n")
room2 = Room("Garden","You are in a garden with many flowers and a narrow stone path. \nTo the north, you see the backdoor of your house that enters your bedroom.\nA pathway leads west.","y")
room3 = Room("Pathway","You are in a narrow stone path with hedges on both sides of you.\nTo the east, there is a garden.","y")
room4 = Room("kitchen","You are in a kitchen now.\nTo the north, there is a Pathway.\nTo the east, there is a dining room.\nTo the south, there is a familyroom","y")
room5 = Room("diningroom","You are in a dining room now.\nTo the north, there is a garden.\nTo the west, there is a kitchen.","y")
room6 = Room("familyroom","You are in a family room.\nTo the north, there is a kitchen.","y")

room7 = Room("room7","You are in a room 7.","y")
room8 = Room("room8","You are in a room 8.","y")
room9 = Room("room9","You are in a room 9.","y")
room10 = Room("room10","You are in a room 10.","y")
room11 = Room("room11","You are in a room 11.","y")
room12 = Room("room12","You are in a room 12.","y")

# Room coordinates (had to create all the rooms to assign them to coordinates)
room1.coordinates = [0,0,room2,0]
room2.coordinates = [room1,0,room5,room3]
room3.coordinates = [0,room2,room4,0]
room4.coordinates = [room3,room5,room6,0]
room5.coordinates = [room2,0,0,room4]
room6.coordinates = [room4,0,0,0]

room7.coordinates = [room6,room8,0,0]
room8.coordinates = [0,room9,0,room7]
room9.coordinates = [0,0,room10,room8]
room10.coordinates = [room9,0,room11,0]
room11.coordinates = [room10,0,0,room12]
room12.coordinates = [0,room11,0,0]

# Character class
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self,name,location = room1):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location

    def look(self):
        place = self.location
        print (place.description)
        if place.gem_y_n == "y":
            pick = input("If you want to pick the Gem y/n :")
            if place.gem != 0 and pick == "y":
                room_gem = place.gem
                print ("You pick a",room_gem.name,"in this room.\n")

        else:
            print ("")

user = Player("Shan")
currentchar = user

print ("Welcome to Mouche's first text based game.")
print ("")
print ('Type "commands" to see the command list')
print ("You are currently:", currentchar.name)

# Menu
# "commands" shows the commands available
# "look" looks around in the current room
#
while True:
    command = input("")
    if command == "commands":
        print ('"n","e","s", and "w" make your character go north, east, south, and west respectively')
        print ('"end" to break')
        print ('"look" to look around the room')

    if command == "look":
        currentchar.look()
    if command == ("n" or "north"):
        if currentchar.location.coordinates[0] == 0:
            print ("You cannot go that way.")
        else:
            currentchar.location = currentchar.location.coordinates[0]
            currentchar.look()
    if command == ("e" or "east"):
        if currentchar.location.coordinates[1] == 0:
            print ("You cannot go that way.")
        else:
            currentchar.location = currentchar.location.coordinates[1]
            currentchar.look()
    if command == ("s" or "south"):
        if currentchar.location.coordinates[2] == 0:
            print ("You cannot go that way.")
        else:
            currentchar.location = currentchar.location.coordinates[2]
            currentchar.look()
    if command == ("w" or "west"):
        if currentchar.location.coordinates[3] == 0:
            print ("You cannot go that way.")
        else:
            currentchar.location = currentchar.location.coordinates[3]
            currentchar.look()
    if command == "end":
        break
```

Comment: Each Stack Overflow question should be about a narrow, specific technical problem. You need to try to implement a feature yourself before you can encounter _any_ technical problems in the course of doing so -- and a [mre], which our rules call for, will have everything unrelated to that specific technical problem your question is about removed.

Answer (score 0):

To randomly generate something, you can use a random number and then check to see if it is equal to a predetermined number, like this:

```
import random

if random.randint(1, 10) == 1: #Here we have a 1 in 10 chance.
    do_something() #Here you can put your code to spawn a gem, for example.
```

If you wanted a higher chance of spawning a gem, you can change the random number range

```
import random

if random.randint(1, 5) == 1: #Now we have a 1 in 5 chance.
     do_something()
```